# load error for rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I cannot run `rake db:migrate`. This is the error I get:

1. `bundle install`
2. `bundle show rake` gives `/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7`
3. `rake db:migrate`gives the error `/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in`load': no such file to load -- /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake (LoadError)
   from /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'`

I'm aware of the rake 0.9.2 error and hence i'm using rake 0.8.7. My Gemfile has the following:

`source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'devise'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'jquery-rails'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: `bundle exec` makes all executables for the gems specified in the Gemfile available inside the gem environment. For more info, http://goo.gl/1sXiz